# Unable to kill CassandraDaemon

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, kill

I am using source installation of cassandra. After installation I ran it like this:

```
$ pwd
/var/users/ec2-user/apache-cassandra-3.10
$ bin/cassandra -f
```

After this I am getting error:

```
ERROR [main] 2017-04-04 14:40:34,195 CassandraDaemon.java:752 - Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

Then I grep for 7199

```
$ ps aux | grep 7199
-javaagent:/home/ec2-user/apache-cassandra-3    .10/bin/../lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199
....
org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
```

Now I am unable to kill `CassandraDaemon`

```
kill -9 <process_id_of_CassandraDaemon>
```

or

```
pkill -f CassandraDaemon
```

This is not working. I get 7199 still running .
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this at a time:

1. Try to run these commands with sudo.
2. `sudo service cassandra stop` (if you are running on ubuntu).
3. Restart server :)

Answer (score 0):

`7199` is not the process id. It actually a port.

execute this command and find which program already acquired this port.

```
> netstat -antp | grep 7199
```

Then use kill command to terminate that program. After then try running cassandra again.

Comment: I know 7199 is not any process id. I grep  it because my cassandraDeamon was using this port to run.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by self.
my cassandra was running under `supervisord` so I had to stop `supervisord` by running following command

`sudo /etc/init.d/supervisord stop`

Then I can kill cassandra process.